# Force close error in Android app debugging

Tags: java, android, android-widget

I get no compilation errors or even significant warnings, yet when I run the program, it force closes and the log tells me there's some kind of error on a line. It succeeded once, but I don't know how or when.

onClick method:

```
public TextView equation;
public TextView answer11;
public TextView answer12;
public TextView or1;
public TextView or2;

public void SolveOnClick(View view){

    EditText a = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.aValue);
    EditText b = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.bValue);       //screws up somewhere here
        EditText c = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.cValue);
        equation = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.equationText);
        answer11 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.answer1);
        answer12 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.answer2);
        or1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.or1);
        or2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.or2);

    double A = Double.parseDouble(a.getText().toString());
        double B = Double.parseDouble(b.getText().toString());
        double C = Double.parseDouble(c.getText().toString());


        Formula(A,B,C);

    }
```

My main graphical layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:onClick="SolveOnClick"
    android:text="@string/solveButtonText" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/quadFormText"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView4"
    android:text="@string/A"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/aValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/bValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/aValue"
    android:layout_below="@+id/aValue"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/cValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bValue"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bValue"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/answer1Text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/equals1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/answer2Text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/answer1Text"
    android:layout_below="@+id/answer1Text"
    android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
    android:text="@string/equals2"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/answer1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/answer1Text"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/answer1Text"
    android:text="@string/answer11"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/or1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/answer1Text"
    android:layout_below="@+id/answer1Text"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:text="@string/or1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/answer2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/answer2Text"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/answer1Text"
    android:text="@string/answer12"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/or2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/answer2Text"
    android:layout_below="@+id/answer2Text"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="@string/or2"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/equationText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cValue"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="@string/equation"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cValue"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView4"
    android:text="@string/C"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bValue"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
    android:text="@string/B"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

onCreate method:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

One of the logs when the program fails:

```
04-26 20:39:33.174: E/AndroidRuntime(16092): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:     android.widget.TextView
04-26 20:39:33.174: E/AndroidRuntime(16092):    at calc.ulater.QuadCalcActivity.SolveOnClick(QuadCalcActivity.java:31)
```

I believe this has something to do with the decimal text boxes. The program worked well before I made them only take decimal numbers, but it also worked a time or two after. I'd rather not show the rest of my code, unless you guys are sure the problem lies there.

Comment: can you which line the error contain

Comment: The (EditText)findViewByID ones. Every time I run the program, one of them gets an error, but not always the same one. Like I said, it's not a compilation error.

Answer (score 2):

If this is the line that's screwing up:

```
EditText b = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.bValue);
```

Then its saying you're trying to cast a `TextView` to an `EditText`.

What's line 31? That one?

Answer (score 1):

```
EditText a = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.aValue);
EditText b = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.bValue);       //screws up somewhere here
EditText c = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.cValue);
equation = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.equationText);
answer11 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.answer1);
answer12 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.answer2);
or1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.or1);
or2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.or2);
```

all the initialization must be done in `onCreate()` and not in the `constructor`

Updated::

```
EditText a = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.aValue);
EditText b = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.bValue);       //screws up somewhere here
EditText c = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.cValue);
equation = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.equationText);
answer11 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.answer1);
answer12 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.answer2);
or1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.or1);
or2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.or2);
```

if view  is your parent view

Comment: Doesn't work. Now it forces close before it shows up, meaning the same error occurs in the onCreate now.

Comment: Please take note that I'm not creating the EditText's and TextView's in the class file. I do it via graphic layout and it auto-generates code in the main.xml. I'm simply trying to find the number a user inputs using the TextEdits, and it gives me a force close error

Comment: Added my onCreate. I just realized that I can't put the code in the onCreate. The editText code grabs the value of the text boxes in the program. The user must make their input before I can grab it. I'm not sure you understand my code or goals.

Comment: wh yyou can put it oncreate and why you are passing view as argument

Comment: Because the code that caused the error takes the text from the text boxes on the "form". The value would always be null(or whatever the boxes string) if I did it from the onCreate. Anyway I fixed it. I'm not sure why I'm passing view as an argument. I don't know what that is.I'm new to Android development and found that this works lol. Thanks for trying.